# replace edit and delete with icon

Tags: php

i need to change the edit and delete button on this table with icons

im trying too much with 500 error :(

```
   echo "<tr>";
   echo "<td>{$userSet['user_id']}</td>";
   echo "<td>{$userSet['username']}</td>";
   echo "<td>{$userSet['password']}</td>";
   echo "<td><a href='delete_user.php?user_id={$userSet['user_id']}'>Delete</a></td>";
   echo "<td><a href='edit_user.php?user_id={$userSet['user_id']}'>Edit</a></td>";
   echo "</tr>";
```

Comment: You'll need to give more information than this if you want help.

Comment: like what ? tell me what to share with you and i'll share it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put img tag inside the a href attribute.

```
 echo "<td><a href='delete_user.php?user_id={$userSet['user_id']}'><img src='path/to/img'></a></td>";
 echo "<td><a href='edit_user.php?user_id={$userSet['user_id']}'><img src='path/to/img'></a></td>";
```

Comment: What did you put in the img tag? And please show more necessary code.

Comment: If that fixed your problem, please accept this as the correct answer :) Thanks.